# Sklearn SGDClassifier "Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2" with after reshaping MNIST

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am new to python and ml and was just trying to work around with mnist
 my program looks like this

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import numpy as np

mist=fetch_openml('mnist_784',version=1)
mist.keys()
x,y=mist['data'],mist['target']
x.shape
images = x[1]
images=images.reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(images)
plt.show()
y=y.astype(np.uint8)
y[0]
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=x[:60000],x[60000:],y[:60000],y[60000:]
ytrain_5=(ytrain==5)
ytest_5=(ytest==5)
sgd = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd.fit(xtrain,ytrain_5)
sgd.predict([images])
```

And is throwing and error:

**Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line:

```
sgd.predict(images.reshape(1, 784))
```

The algorithm was trained with a flattened array of shape `(70000, 784)`, so you need to flatten `images` to shape `(1, 784)` before you pass it through. You had previously reshaped it to `(28, 28)`.

Full code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import numpy as np

mist=fetch_openml('mnist_784',version=1)
x,y=mist['data'],mist['target']
images = x[1]
images=images.reshape(28,28)
y=y.astype(np.uint8)
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=x[:60000],x[60000:],y[:60000],y[60000:]
ytrain_5=(ytrain==5)
ytest_5=(ytest==5)
sgd = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd.fit(xtrain,ytrain_5)
sgd.predict(images.reshape(1, 784))
```

Comment: I don't think so. Copy&paste the code above and you'll see. The only thing I changed is the line I mentioned.

Comment: thnaks @Nicolas that worked , i seriously dont know why it didnt worked for the first time I tried.